# How to set Dynamic height of a element in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

i'm not able to set the height of Div element dynamically using Angular 4 typescript..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Use a variable which has the height you want to enter... then use [ngStyle]="{'height': [yourVariableName]}"

Comment: Thank you very much i was trying since 1 day not able to find this working syntax

Comment: Glad that helped you, can you accept the answer as well ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use a variable which has the height you want to enter... then use [ngStyle]="{'height': [yourVariableName]}"

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by using **[style.height]** as follow:

```
 //shouldExpand  is a condition, you can replace it with  your condition
<div class="yourClass"
[style.height]="shouldExpand === true ? '100px' : '70px'">
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can add styles for two classes like 
   .class1 {height:20px} 
   .class2 {height:40px}

And for div add [class] = "ifSomething ? 'class1' : 'class2'"

2. Use ElementRef.nativeElement.getElementByClassName and change style for div by js.